# Is there a way to change an element's default getter?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, appendchild

I'm writing a userscript and need to make it so any `iframe` appended to the DOM with `document.body.appendChild()`'s content document has the `hidden` getter set to always return false.
I can change the getter with:

```js
iframe.contentDocument.__defineGetter__("hidden",()=>false)
```

I need this to modify elements before they're added to the DOM, so that

```js
var i = document.createElement("iframe");
i.sandbox = "allow-same-origin";
document.body.appendChild(i);
document.__defineGetter__("hidden", i.contentDocument.__lookupGetter__("hidden"))
```

will always redefine the document `hidden` getter to return false.
I've tried:

```js
const oldAppend = Node.prototype.appendChild;
Node.prototype.appendChild = function (child) {
  child?.contentDocument?.__defineGetter__("hidden",()=>false);
  return oldAppend(child);
}
```

But then when I try to use the `appendChild` method, I get: `TypeError: 'appendChild' called on an object that does not implement interface Node.`

Is there a way (in pure JS) to change the `appendChild` method so that it does this for every `iframe` that gets appended to the DOM?

Comment: You can redefine `Node.prototype.appendChild` to do this.

Comment: @Barmar I got the error `TypeError: 'appendChild' called on an object that does not implement interface Node.` when I tried that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MutationObserver to watch for nodes added anywhere in the document, and patch them if they haven't been patched yet.

```js
// userscript code
const parsed = new WeakSet();
const parse = iframe => {
  if (parsed.has(iframe)) return;
  parsed.add(iframe);
  Object.defineProperty(iframe, 'hidden', { get() { return false; } });
};
new MutationObserver(() => {
  document.querySelectorAll('iframe').forEach(parse);
})
  .observe(document.documentElement, { childList: true, subtree: true });

// site code
const iframe = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('iframe'));
console.log(iframe.hidden);
```

`Object.defineProperty` should be preferred over `__defineGetter__`, which is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/__defineGetter__).

A MutationObserver is probably a bit better than working with only `appendChild` because `appendChild` is not the only way that nodes can be added to the document. (A MutationObserver will catch everything)

Comment: I should have specified I need it to specifically do this before the iframe gets added to the DOM. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem by redefining `document.body.appendChild` like this:

```js
const oldAppend = Node.prototype.appendChild;
document.body.appendChild = function(...args) {
  const toReturn = oldAppend.call(this, ...args);
  
  if (args[0].nodeName === "IFRAME") {
    args[0].contentDocument.__defineGetter__("hidden",()=>false);
  }
  
  return toReturn;
}
```